# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing Python Calculator

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

I have a calculator in Python 3 but for some reason my code doesn't work. It works fine until I press the "=" button to calculate my thing (using tkinter for the gui). Here is my code (it is quite long, sorry for that, it is just a part from my code)

---

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter.ttk import *

    def SMATH():

        #PUT TEXT IN ENTRY FUNCTION

        def puttext(text):
            sm_ent.insert(0,text)
            return

        #CLEAR THE ENTRY FUNCTION

        def cleartext():
            sm_ent.delete(0, END)
            return

        #GET THE OUTCOME FUNCTION

        def Coutcome():
            calc = caltext.get()
            answer = eval(calc)
            sm_ent = Entry(e_frame, textvariable=caltext, text=answer)

        smathW = Tk()
        smathW.title("Simple Math")
        smathW.resizable(0,0)
        smathW.wm_iconbitmap('icon.ico')

        def quitSmath():
            smathW.destroy()

        #ENTRY FRAME
        e_frame = Frame(smathW)
        e_frame.pack()

        #BUTTONS FRAME

        b_frame = Frame(smathW)
        b_frame.pack()

        #ENTRY
        caltext= StringVar()
        sm_ent = Entry(e_frame, textvariable=caltext)
        sm_ent.pack(fill=Y)

        #LABEL

        sm_inf = Label(smathW, text="Here is the Simple Math mode from CalfoWin")
        sm_inf.pack()

        #BUTTON 7

        sm_butt0 = Button(b_frame, text="7", command=lambda: puttext('7'))
        sm_butt0.grid(row=1, column=0)

        #BUTTON 8

        sm_butt1 = Button(b_frame, text="8", command=lambda: puttext('8'))
        sm_butt1.grid(row=1, column=1)

        #BUTTON 9

        sm_butt2 = Button(b_frame, text="9", command=lambda: puttext('9'))
        sm_butt2.grid(row=1, column=2)

        #BUTTON 4

        sm_butt3 = Button(b_frame, text="4", command=lambda: puttext('4'))
        sm_butt3.grid(row=2, column=0)

        #BUTTON 5

        sm_butt4 = Button(b_frame, text="5", command=lambda: puttext('5'))
        sm_butt4.grid(row=2, column=1)

        #BUTTON 6

        sm_butt5 = Button(b_frame, text="6", command=lambda: puttext('6'))
        sm_butt5.grid(row=2, column=2)

        #BUTTON 1

        sm_butt6 = Button(b_frame, text="1", command=lambda: puttext('1'))
        sm_butt6.grid(row=3, column=0)

        #BUTTON 2

        sm_butt7 = Button(b_frame, text="2", command=lambda: puttext('2'))
        sm_butt7.grid(row=3, column=1)

        #BUTTON 3

        sm_butt8 = Button(b_frame, text="3", command=lambda: puttext('3'))
        sm_butt8.grid(row=3, column=2)

        #BUTTON 0
        sm_butt9 = Button(b_frame, text="0", command=lambda: puttext('0'))
        sm_butt9.grid(row=4, column=0)

        #BUTTON KOMMA

        sm_buttKomma = Button(b_frame, text=".", command=lambda: puttext('.'))
        sm_buttKomma.grid(row=4, column=1)

        #BUTTON EQUALSIGN!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

        sm_buttEsign = Button(b_frame, text="=", command=Coutcome())
        sm_buttEsign.grid(row=4, column=2)

        #BUTTON ADDITION

        sm_buttPlus = Button(b_frame, text="+", command=lambda: puttext('+'))
        sm_buttPlus.grid(row=2, column=3)

        #BUTTON SUBTRACKTION

        sm_buttMin = Button(b_frame, text="-", command=lambda: puttext('-'))
        sm_buttMin.grid(row=3, column=3)

        #BUTTON DIVISION

        sm_buttDiv = Button(b_frame, text="/", command=lambda: puttext('/'))
        sm_buttDiv.grid(row=3, column=4)

        #BUTTON MULTIPLICATION

        sm_buttMult = Button(b_frame, text='x', command=lambda: puttext('*'))
        sm_buttMult.grid(row=2, column=4)

        #BUTTON CLEAR

        sm_buttClear = Button(b_frame, text="Clear", command=lambda: cleartext())
        sm_buttClear.grid(row=1, column=3)

        #BUTTON QUIT

        sm_buttquit = Button(b_frame, text="Quit", command=lambda: quitSmath())
        sm_buttquit.grid(row=1, column=4)
```

Comment: Have you entered a valid Python expression? This is exactly the error you'll get if you don't. You probably want to catch it and throw up an error message.

Comment: yes is just type math but thank you for making me remeber to write a function to deal with errors :)

Answer (score 1):

You use `command = Coutcome()` which passes the return value of `Coutcome` as the funtion to call when the button is pressed. So what happens now is that `Coutcome` is called when the button is created, and `caltext` is still empty. This means that you are running `eval('')`, which gives you the error you are seeing.

This is not what you want, you want `Coutcome` to be called when the button is pressed. So You should pass the function name, without parentheses, as the command

```
sm_buttEsign = Button(b_frame, text="=", command=Coutcome)
```

---

For your quit and clear buttons you should do the same thing, get rid of the parentheses and the lambda. The reason you need to use lambda sometimes is because when you have to leave out the parentheses, you can't pass variables to the command. When you don't need to pass variables, the lambda is superfluous.

---

In addition, you should be careful using `eval`. With the wrong input, it can [be dangerous](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html). So watch out with letting users input stuff to `eval` without proper restrictions.

Comment: Hi, i did what you said (and i understand what you said and it was very helpful) but my = button still doesnt work, here is the whole error message:The Python REPL process has exited
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1533, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Ian\Documents\Programming\Python 3.4.2\CalfoWin\CalfoWin Demo v0.01\CalfoWin Demo v0_01.pyw", line 43, in Coutcome
    answer = eval(calc)
  File "<string>", line 0
    
    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing